# Ajax tree does not load page

Tags: ajax, jsf, treeview, primefaces

I tried to alternate pages using `ui:include` on click of ajax (PrimeFaces) treenodes. The first page that load by default loads properly with all the components active but when I click on the other treenode to display another page, the latter page loads abnormally like having the dialog box visible below and the page hands.

I feel if I can force the page to reload partially as default on `nodeSelect`

`index.jsf` (gets loaded on login)

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="270" header="Menu" collapsible="false" resizable="true">
    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:16px;height:16px;">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:graphicImage value="../design/ajaxloading.gif"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="complete">
            <h:outputText value=""/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>
    <h:form id="appsMainControl">
        <ui:include src="/ui/appServices.jsf"/>
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <h:form id="centerControl">                    
        <ui:include src="/ui/#{amb.appToGet}.jsf"/>                   
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

The treeview component with the listener action. On node selection I want the child page to load appropriately

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="270" header="Menu" collapsible="false" resizable="true">
    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:16px;height:16px;">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:graphicImage value="../design/ajaxloading.gif"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="complete">
            <h:outputText value=""/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>
    <h:form id="appsMainControl">
        <ui:include src="/ui/appServices.jsf"/>
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <h:form id="centerControl">                    
        <ui:include src="/ui/#{amb.appToGet}.jsf"/>                   
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

The backing bean:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) throws Exception {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    try {
        appToGet = appsMainDAO.appToGet(event.getTreeNode().toString());
        // ec.redirect("index.jsf");
        // System.out.println("Got "+appToGet);
        // appSubList = appsMainDAO.appsSubServicesList(appToGet, "Forms");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(appsMainBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. You are rubbing JSF the wrong way and thus heading into a major catastrophe.

It's impossible to explain the whole life cycle here, but - until you really know your way around JSF - just assume that facelet pages are _not_supposed_ to work like HTML pages.

Instead, they should work like window applications, where you have a certain number of widgets that don't really appear or disappear - they can be put in tabs, they can become disabled, but they stay where they were from the beginning.

If there is a finite number of things to include, the easiest option is to include them all and add some rendered="#{gui.current=='component1'}", so only one of the components is visible.

Comment: Thank dreger. i think you are right. although at the same time i feel implementing that on a single page impairs performance as all the pages will load at the same time and only the one to render stays. I got it working by adding the missing html and body tags to the ui:composition template. I assumed the index.jsf will reload all the component to default. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Damilola: well, it you understand the implications of what you did (concerning the life cycle of view scoped beans, navigation etc), then of course go ahead. btw: trusting your feelings does not have to be the best way of optimizing applications (although it certainly may work).